# Swapping last node of the linked list is going into a infinte -- C++

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Below is the code,

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class node{
public:
    int data;
    node * next;

    node(){
        this->next = NULL;
    }

    node(int data){
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
};

class linkedList{
public:
    node * head;
    node * tail;

    linkedList(){
        this->head = NULL;
    }

    void getTail(node *& t){
        t = head;
        while(t->next != NULL){
            t = t->next;
        }
    }

    void insertAtEnd(int data){
        node * newNode = new node(data);

        if(head == NULL){
            head = newNode;
            return;
        }

        node * temp = head;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }

    void print(){
        node * temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL){
            printf("%d->", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("NULL\n");
    }

    void swap(node *& a, node *& b){ 
        node * temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp; 
    } 

    void swapNode(node ** start, node ** end){
        swap(*start, *end);
        swap(((*start)->next), (*end)->next);
    }
};

int main(){
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    linkedList * ll1 = new linkedList(); //
    ll1->insertAtEnd(6);                 //
    ll1->insertAtEnd(2);                 //
    ll1->insertAtEnd(1);                 //
    ll1->insertAtEnd(3);                 //
    ll1->print();                        /////////////////////
    ll1->swapNode(&ll1->head, &ll1->head->next->next->next);// ----> This is working
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    linkedList * ll2 = new linkedList();
    ll2->insertAtEnd(6);
    ll2->insertAtEnd(2);
    ll2->insertAtEnd(1);
    ll2->insertAtEnd(3);
    ll2->print();
    node * tail;
    ll2->getTail(tail);
    ll2->swapNode(&ll2->head, &tail); // This is not working // Going into a infinte loop
    ll2->print();

}
```

When the tail node is stored in some other variable there seems be a forever loop.
While the code is working when the tail node is given by traversing to last using next pointer.

So, below is the output for the first example of the linked list, that is,
6->2->1->3->NULL
1->2->6->3->NULL

For the linked list #2, the output goes like this
6->2->1->3->NULL
3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2->1->3->2-> there's no ending

Comment: For the first example, shouldn't the list become `3->2->1->6->NULL` after swapping, not `1->2->6->3->NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pictures often help when dealing with linked lists. Here is the starting list.

```
head
 |
 V
 ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------    
 | 6 | next | -> | 2 | next | -> | 1 | next | -> | 3 | NULL |
 ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------
```

Now we'll call `ll1->swapNode(&ll1->head, &ll1->head->next->next->next)`, which adds two variables to the picture.

```
start
  |
  V
  head                                  end
   |                                     |
   V                                     V
   ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------    
   | 6 | next | -> | 2 | next | -> | 1 | next | -> | 3 | NULL |
   ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------
```

Next is the call to `swap(*start, *end)`, which swaps the head pointer and the `next` pointer in the node whose data is `1`. So the head pointer will point to the `3` node, while the `1` node will point to the `6` node.

```
                                              start
                                                |
                                                V
                                      end       head
                                       |         |
                                       V         V
 ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------    
 | 6 | next | -> | 2 | next | -> | 1 | next |    | 3 | NULL |
 ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------    
 ^                                      |
 |                                      |
 L---------------------------------------
```

Finally, the call to `swap(((*start)->next), (*end)->next)`, which swaps the `next` pointers in the nodes whose data is `3` and `6`. So the `3` node will point to the `2` node, while the `6` node's pointer will become null.

```
       start
         |
         V
         head
          |
          V
          ------------
          | 3 | next |
          ------------                end
                 |                     |
                 V                     V
 ------------    ------------    ------------
 | 6 | NULL |    | 2 | next | -> | 1 | next |
 ------------    ------------    ------------
 ^                                      |
 |                                      |
 L---------------------------------------
```

Hooray! The nodes were swapped.

---

Now look at the call `ll2->swapNode(&ll2->head, &tail);`, which adds three variables to the initial picture.

```
start                                            end
  |                                               |
  V                                               V
  head                                            tail
   |                                               |
   V                                               V
   ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------    
   | 6 | next | -> | 2 | next | -> | 1 | next | -> | 3 | NULL |
   ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------
```

Next is the call to `swap(*start, *end)`, which swaps the head pointer and `tail` (not the tail pointer of the list, but the variable local to `main()`).

```
 end                                            start
  |                                               |
  V                                               V
  tail                                            head
   |                                               |
   V                                               V
   ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------    
   | 6 | next | -> | 2 | next | -> | 1 | next | -> | 3 | NULL |
   ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------
```

There's already a noticeable difference from the first case in that the nodes of the list are unchanged. Hmm... well, let's keep going and call `swap(((*start)->next), (*end)->next)`, which swaps the `next` pointers in the nodes whose data is `3` and `6`. So the `3` node will point to the `2` node, while the `6` node's pointer will become null. *This is what happened in the first case, so will it work out?*

```
 end                                            start
  |                                               |
  V                                               V
  tail                                            head
   |                                               |
   V                                               V
   ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------    
   | 6 | NULL |    | 2 | next | -> | 1 | next | -> | 3 | next |
   ------------    ------------    ------------    ------------    
                   ^                                      |
                   |                                      |
                   L---------------------------------------
```

PROBLEM! We are left with a cycle! What happened to the step where the `1` node was changed to point to the `6` node? That's right, we changed `tail` instead, and the result was disaster.

---

I would recommend three main things to move your code to more robust ground. (That is, don't try to fix your current error yet. Do these first as they'll change the playing field.)

1. Get rid of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`; instead include the headers you need. For this example, you need just `#include <cstdio>`.
2. Make `node` a `private` implementation detail of `linkedList`. Robustness tends to increase along with encapsulation. If no one knows the data structures used by `linkedList`, you limit what other code can do. With fewer possibilities to account for, it's easier to make sure you accounted for all of them.
3. Don't declare a field (`linkedList::tail`) that is never used. Someone will want to use that field at some point without realizing it contains garbage.

(There are other improvements to be made. These three are the most important in my view.)

Answer (score 3):

When you swap two nodes `a` and `b` you must also fix the pointers reaching `a` and reaching `b`. For example

```
     x1 -> x2 -> a -> x3 -> x4 -> b -> x5 -> x6 -> NULL
```

to swap nodes `a` and `b` to don't need to fix only `a.next` and `b.next` but also `x2.next` and `x4.next`.

That part of code is missing from your implementation.

Comment: ll1->swapNode(&ll1->head, &ll1->head->next->next->next);
Then why is it working with this piece of code?